# MySQL query to output multiple SUM values based on another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL database with hundred of thousands of payments stored as (not all columns are listed) :

| ID | the_date | type | store_location | terminal | paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-18 | Credit Card | 1 | 2 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 2022-05-18 | Debit Card | 1 | 1 | 10.00 |
| 3 | 2022-05-18 | Cash | 1 | 1 | 50.00 |
| 4 | 2022-05-18 | Credit Card | 1 | 2 | 20.00 |
| 5 | 2022-05-18 | Cash | 1 | 2 | 10.00 |
| 6 | 2022-05-18 | Debit Card | 1 | 2 | 100.00 |

What I want to accomplish is show SUM results for each "type" without using foreach statements shuffling through every record which have proven to be very slow for large queries...

Basically the output should be like this :

```
Cash = 60.00
Credit Card = 22.00
Debit Card = 110.00
```

The current SQLi query is taking too much time when pulling monthly or quarterly statements.
Here is the current query string :

```
$payments = dbquery_array("SELECT ticket_id, paid, type FROM payments WHERE location LIKE '".$location."' AND the_date BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' ORDER BY id ASC");
if(is_array($payments)){
    foreach($payments as $paid){
        if($paid['type'] != "Trade-In" && $paid['type'] != "Reward Balance"){
            $total_income['All']['Total'] += $paid['paid'];
            $total_income['Type'][$paid['type']] += $paid['paid'];
            $ticket = dbquery("SELECT id, taxable FROM tickets WHERE id = '".$paid['ticket_id']."'");
            $counted_tickets[] = $ticket['id'];
            $exists = array_count_values($counted_tickets);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to join the data, then not need the second query. Also should parameterize the values and use prepared statements. Also, if you dont need those 2 types you could exclude in the SQL.

Comment: That is a regular grouping: `SELECT type, SUM(paid) AS paid_subtotal FROM payments GROUP BY \`type\`;`

Comment: I am wanting to have different SUM outputs based on what the payment type is.  Maybe I need to do 2 SQL queries, one for selecting DISTINCT payment type, then another to SUM based on the payment type?

@Jared Yes, currently it is normal grouping...  I need to separate SUM results based on the type of payment

Comment: With a `GROUP BY \`type\`` you will get an aggregated output, each row will contain a sum for distinct type. And you will get as much rows as much distinct types you have. Another option is using window functions like
`SELECT type, SUM(paid) OVER(PARTITION BY \`type\` ) AS paid_subtotal, SUM(paid) OVER() AS paid_total FROM payments`;
But this will give you all the rows (limited by `WHERE` and `LIMIT` clauses) with columns `paid_subtotal` - sum aggregated by type - and `paid_total` - sum overall. But this might be unwanted for lots of data.